# css hide the no image icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

```
img.profile-picture{
        width:80px;
        min-height: 80px;
        float: left;
        background-image: url("/images/user-4.png");
    }
```

The above CSS sets the background of a profile pic image to a nice place holder for when the user has not uploaded their own profile picture.

Where the image tag looks like:

```
<img class="pull-left profile-picture" ng-src="{{profilePicturePath}}"/>
```

The problem is, when there is no image at the set path I get the missing image icon:
[image]

It seems very over the top to query each time if the user has a profile picture or not before the page is loaded, and it is a waste of server HDD space to created a placeholder image for each user.

Is it possible to just hide the no image icon?

Comment: what about trying to do it in js? `img.onerror=function(){this.src='/images/user-4.png'}`

Comment: _“It seems very over the top to query each time if the user has a profile picture or not before the page is loaded, and it is a waste of server HDD space to created a placeholder image for each user”_ – you don’t create one for each user, you use _one_ placeholder image and output the path to that, if the user has no individual profile picture set. That’s not over the top, but common sense. Letting the browser try to load an image even if you know upfront that it doesn’t exists – now that would be nonsense.

Comment: ok, but then i still need to somehow calculate if the user has a profile picture which is work for the server. If i can just offset this to the client and not display the broken image thing then this is better for performance. plus the image is downloaded via css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `onerror` attribute to the `img` tag

```
<img src="brokenimage.jpg" onerror="this.style.display='none'">
```

To maintain the *no-profile* picture, I would wrap the image with a `div`, where the background is set with the no-profile.jpg pic

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
<img ng-if="profilePicturePath" class="pull-left profile-picture" ng-src="{{profilePicturePath}}"/>
<img ng-if="!profilePicturePath" class="pull-left profile-picture">
```